# как разбить строку на структуру с++

Tags: c++, struct

```
Титаник 1024 jpg 150 320 500 32

struct picture
{
    char name[LineLength];
    int size;
    char format[LineLength];
    int width;
    int height;
    int dpi;
    int depth;
};
```

Comment: Функции strcpy и atoi определенно помогут. Ну и strchr для поиска следующего поля

Answer (score 1):

Проще всего, пожалуй, так:

```
string s = "Титаник 1024 jpg 150 320 500 32";
picture p;
istringstream is(s);

is >> p.name >> p.size >> p.format >> p.width >> p.height >> p.dpi >> p.depth;

cout <<  p.name << endl;
cout <<  p.size << endl;
cout <<  p.format << endl;
cout <<  p.width << endl;
```

Только вот нужно обеспечить гарантию, что места в буфере для строк хватит, или сделать эти поля `string` и не мучиться.